# How to list all Google Tasks by due date regardless of what list it is present on?

Tags: gmail, google-tasks

I have several lists of Google tasks, I have an app for my iPad that lists all Google tasks regardless of what list it is from by due date.  So it does appear the API supports doing this.

I'm looking for a similar feature when using the browser/Windows.  On my PC I tend to use this URL (https://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas?pli=1) to get a 'full screen' version of tasks, but I still must look through each list to find out what is due today/tomorrow.

Comment: Use Asana , i migrated to it for the same reason . Asana notifies you each day about the work that you have to finish and when it's due .

Comment: Simply telling someone to switch to another service doesn't really answer the question (even if the service they are using doesn't support the functionality they are after).

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem possible. Further, Google Tasks has been mostly deprecated in favor of Reminders, so I doubt there will be any further development by Google to improve Tasks.